# Python BeautifulSoup Web Scraping works for the first but not second or any following times

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request, screen-scraping

im a Python newbie and try to script a web scraper to get my hands on some price data.
The website i am trying to scrape is for example:
https://www.medizinfuchs.de/?params%5Bsearch%5D=10192710&params%5Bsearch_cat%5D=1

I am using following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.medizinfuchs.de/?params%5Bsearch%5D=11484834&params%5Bsearch_cat%5D=1"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for price in soup.select('li.apotheke div.price'):
        print(float(price.text.strip(' \t\n€').replace(',', '.')))

for name in soup.select('li.apotheke a.name'):
        print(str(name.text.strip(' \t\n€')))
```

It works like a charm the first time I run it, but after that I dont get an output...

The Output I expect:

> 5.39
> 5.4
> 5.4
> 5.65
> 5.8
> 5.89
> 5.89
> 5.94 ApothekePrime Apoversand24.de bon-vita.de 1-apo.de eurapon.de docmorris.de sternapo ahorn24.de

Can you help me get it to work consistently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Take a look into your soup - It tells the truth. There is no `<li>` with class `apotheke` in the `soup`, so you wont get any result.

#### How to fix?

Select the right tags or skip them and focus on the `classes` (not the best idea, cause, classes often change, but in this case best you can do)

```
for e in soup.select('.apotheke'):
    print(e.select_one('.price').get_text(strip=True).split(' ')[0])
    
for e in soup.select('.apotheke'):
    print(e.select_one('.name').get_text(strip=True))
```

#### Example (more structured)

```
data=[]
for e in soup.select('.apotheke'):
    data.append({
        'name':e.select_one('.name').get_text(strip=True),
        'price':e.select_one('.price').get_text(strip=True).split(' ')[0]
    })
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'name': 'ApothekePrime', 'price': '5,39'},
 {'name': 'Apoversand24.de', 'price': '5,40'},
 {'name': 'bon-vita.de', 'price': '5,40'},
 {'name': '1-apo.de', 'price': '5,65'},
 {'name': 'eurapon.de', 'price': '5,80'},
 {'name': 'docmorris.de', 'price': '5,89'},
 {'name': 'sternapo', 'price': '5,89'},
 {'name': 'ahorn24.de', 'price': '5,94'}]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! You are my hero :)